# Pushing an `aufs` Docker image into registry and pulling it onto an `overlay2` Docker installation. Possible?

Tags: docker, migration, docker-overlay2

Now that Docker released an upgrade to version `23.0.0` I got an unfriendly reminder that three old Ubuntu installations were still configured to use `aufs` with Docker.

I had to revert to version `20.10.23` in order to be able to start my containers.

According to a chatbot, I can use `docker save` to export the content of the image, then upgrade the system to `23.0.0`, and use `docker load` in order to recreate the image for use with the `overlay2` driver.

Now my question is:

Is it possible to `push` the old, original, unsaved `aufs` images of the `20.10.23` version into a private registry, then upgrade the system to Docker version `23.0.0`, and have `docker run` pull those old images for use with the `overlay2` driver?

Could this cause an undefined behavior because the images in the registry were created with `aufs`, or is this a working migration path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker registry protocols and the `docker save` tar file formats are independent of any particular storage backend.  If you (or your CI system) have an `aufs` Docker installation and push images to a registry, you shouldn't have any trouble pulling them on to an `overlay2` setup.

Also consider that the registry protocol has only really had two major versions, but at various times `devicemapper`, `aufs`, `overlay`, and `overlay2` have all been "the best" storage backend, and Docker Hub itself hasn't needed to do anything special to support this.  Also of note is the appearance of alternate container runtimes like Podman, and Kubernetes's announcement that Docker proper is no longer a recommended container runtime, but these alternate systems still work file with existing image registries.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept it after I have confirmed that it works as expected. Also thanks a lot for the Podman hint. My issue is that I have a lot of tooling around the Python Docker API.